# How to add multiple records in one INSERT in mySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

I know what is the syntax where I could insert multiple records in one line. [(here)](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-statement.aspx).
However, in my case number of incoming records are not fixed hence I am trying to do a workaround so that I could still use the method.

```
INSERT INTO tasks(title, priority)
VALUES
 ('My first task', 1),
 ('It is the second task',2),
 ('This is the third task of the week',3);
```

I have set up my incoming data as follows :

```
foreach (var item in oListing.items)
            {
                string s1 = String.Format("({0},{1},{2})", Enum.GetName(typeof(ItemType), item.itemSize), item.ItemPrice, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
                portion_price.Add(s1);
            }
            string string_portion_price = string.Join(",", portion_price);
```

Then I use "string_portion_price" use with "AddWithValue" as follows :

One of the assembled string is : (SMALL,2.50,3/29/2019 3:06:39 PM)

```
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@string_portion_price", string_portion_price);
```

My SQL statement is :

```
  INSERT INTO listing_price (SIZE, PRICE, PRICES_ADD_CHANGE_DATE)
                                    VALUES @string_portion_price;";
```

I get an error saying there is a syntax error near this SQL statement :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(SMALL,2.50,3/29/2019 3:06:39 PM)'' at line 2
```

Is my way of parameter assignment wrong ? (typically I do it with value assignment.)

What is the best way to insert records to myself table in one insert query ? I could have multiple records to write but number could vary.

Comment: "Is my way of parameter assignment wrong ?" -- Yes. You end up with a query that tries to insert a single string value which is you concatenation. Do do this with parameters you have to dynamically create the query string with as much placeholders as single values and then assign each value to the respective placeholder individually.

Comment: You must know that you need three parameters here for `Size`, `Price` and `Prices_Add_Change_Date` in order to construct your string `INSERT INTO listing_price (SIZE, PRICE, PRICES_ADD_CHANGE_DATE)`, so why not just have three variables/parameters? You could create those three variables/parameters dynamically if you don't know the number while coding.

Comment: Then I have to do multiple inserts. I wan to write all in one insert.